# 'module' object has no attribute 'contrib' error when I train with gcloud and Tensorflow 1.15

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have launched a training job on gcloud. The cloud yaml file specifies a runtimeVersion=1.15 so I suppose that the tensorflow version launched on Google VM is 1.15 right? Training task terminates with error though that seems related to TF2. The error is:

```
...
File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/model_lib.py", line 28, in <module>
from object_detection import exporter as exporter_lib
File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/exporter.py", line 32, in <module>
slim = tf.contrib.slim
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/module_wrapper.py", line 193, in __getattr__
attr = getattr(self._tfmw_wrapped_module, name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'contrib'
```

(contrib module has moved out of TF>=2.0). Am I right when I say that TF version on VM is the bad one and if yes, how can I specify lower version (if it's not with runtimeVersion parameter in config yaml file)?

EDIT: I add the json corresponding to the training input details as seen on AI Platform dashboard:

```
{
  "scaleTier": "CUSTOM",
  "masterType": "standard_gpu",
  "workerType": "standard_gpu",
  "parameterServerType": "standard",
  "workerCount": "5",
  "parameterServerCount": "3",
  "packageUris": [
    "gs://mybucket/detection/train/packages/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz",
    "gs://mybucket/detection/train/packages/slim-0.1.tar.gz",
    "gs://mybucket/detection/train/packages/pycocotools-2.0.tar.gz"
  ],
  "pythonModule": "object_detection.model_main",
  "args": [
    "--train_dir=gs://mybucket/detection/train",
    "--pipeline_config_path=gs://mybucket/detection/data/faster_rcnn_resnet101_dumptruck.config"
  ],
  "region": "us-central1",
  "runtimeVersion": "1.15",
  "jobDir": "gs://mybucket/detection/train"
}
```

The command to launch the training was:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training ${JOB_ID}  \
    --job-dir=${OUTPUT_DIR} \
    --region us-central1     \
    --packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz,/tmp/pycocotools/pycocotools-2.0.tar.gz
    --module-name object_detection.model_main  \
    --config object_detection/samples/cloud/cloud.yml \
    --  \
    --train_dir=${OUTPUT_DIR} \
    --pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH}
```

Comment: Can you provide the yaml file you used? What command did you use prior to encountering the error? Did you follow any documentations for this training?

Comment: Added info in edit section

Comment: You can specify the runtime version in the gcloud command instead of specifying it in the yaml file.

gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
--job-dir $OUTPUT_PATH \
--runtime-version 1.15 \
--python-version 2.7 \
--module-name trainer.task \
--package-path trainer/ \
--region $REGION \
-- \
--train-files $TRAIN_DATA \
--eval-files $EVAL_DATA \
--train-steps 1000 \
--eval-steps 100 \
--verbosity DEBUG

You can also try it in the GCP console UI:

AI Platform -> Models -> Create a New Model -> Create Version -> Pre-built container settings -> ML runtime version

Comment: Runtime version 1.15 supports TensorFlow 1.15.0 for CPU and GPU. Change the runtime version by editing this flag `--runtime-version 1.15`.  Thanks!